# Set the last word of the line to the next line in jtextarea

Tags: java, jtextarea

This may be a very simple question but I don't get any answers from anywhere.

I have a string variable that holds a very long paragraph string, and is intended to be placed on a `JTextArea`, by `.setText(str)`;

My problem is how to make the last word of the line (that do not fit to the right edge on that line) to be transferred on the next line.

An illustration below may help my problem:

Problem:

```
The quick brown fox ju
mps over the lazy dog.
```

Solution needed:

```
The quick brown fox
jumps over the lazy
dog.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Enable Word wrapping to force the Text area to not wrap in the middle of a word.

```
JTextArea c = new JTextArea();
c.setLineWrap(true);
c.setWrapStyleWord(true);
```

Source http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/javax.swing.text/ta_Wrap.html

Comment: Short but contains everything I need. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The JTextArea has a .setLineWrap property. Sounds like thats what you need.

[JTextArea API](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextArea.html#setLineWrap%28boolean%29)

Source code from [Java2s.com](http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaAPI/javax.swing/JTextAreasetLineWrapbooleanwrap.htm):

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JSplitPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;

public class MainClass extends JFrame {

  static String sometext = "Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text ";

  public MainClass() {
    super("Simple SplitPane Frame");
    setSize(450, 200);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    JTextArea jt1 = new JTextArea(sometext);
    JTextArea jt2 = new JTextArea(sometext);

    jt1.setLineWrap(true);
    jt2.setLineWrap(true);
    jt1.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(150, 150));
    jt2.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(150, 150));
    jt1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(250, 200));
    JSplitPane sp = new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.HORIZONTAL_SPLIT, jt1, jt2);
    getContentPane().add(sp, BorderLayout.CENTER);
  }

  public static void main(String args[]) {
    MainClass ssb = new MainClass();
    ssb.setVisible(true);
  }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You can edit your String data just before setting it to the JTextArea using the below code:

```
    StringBuffer sb=new StringBuffer(str);
sb.setCharAt(str.lastIndexOf(" "), '\n');
```

Then after set jtextArea.setText(sb.toString());

Thanks

Comment: This answers the title of the question, but not the question itself, with the example.